# Disable script tags within RTF fields

Tags: rtf

Our client would like to disable the ability to add script tags to RTF fields for all users, or would like a configuration where this can be turned on/off at the environment and potentially, publication and user level.

If we went down the XSLT / schema route, this would be a nightmare to implement and switch on/off, plus if we needed to upgrade later on &c.

Other solutions I can think of are:

- CMS GUI extension that checks the ‘on-save’ of the component
- CMS event system – again checking the ‘on-save’ of the component
- Globally by modifying the ootb default XSLT (I need to research that one a bit)

Just wondering if anyone has also had to implement something similar and had some advice / gotchas that I need to consider.

Thanks

John

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Valid and well known issue, I wondered when it would end up here... But I have to confess I haven't seen a good solution for it either yet. Personally I sticked with the Schema XSLT *nightmare* route. Kept a single Filtering XSLT which should be applied to all Format Area fields.

Looking at your option list I'm wondering why I never picked the Event System, since that is one that appeals to me. I think that can be implemented rather cleanly keeping it simple and effective.

Only added benefit of a UI extension would be to be able to directly notify the user before he presses the Save & Close button (using the Initiated phase could be close enough, that still happens while the window is open). But I think the implementation is a lot less trivial than an Event System would be.

Last option I wouldn't suggest, I bet it's not a supported one so voids your warranty (might be wrong there if the default XSLT is user editable, it should mention that in there once you find it).

Comment: Congrats on the 3k!

Comment: Thx, you congrats on making #2 this week http://stackexchange.com/leagues/233/week/tridion

Comment: Thanks for the comments @BartKoopman - we've gone for the event system route :)

Answer (score 4):

For configurable RTF-related requirements consider:

- **Embedded schemas** to make the XSLT filtering modular.
- **Flipping the requirement** by restricting script by default with an XSLT filter that removes `<script>` tags.

  - Let only certain groups add script in RTF <strike>(or maybe just in "code" components)</strike> with embedded component presentations ([content injection](http://www.tridionworld.com/articles/understanding_content_injection.aspx)).
  - The code can exist outside the RTF but keep a reference (component link) or
  - Escape the markup for the script and leave it in the RTF
- **During publish "inject" the script** or transform it back with template logic.

This gives you control without changing what's in the RTFs.

- **Fewer RTF and XSLT filters** to maintain
- **Configuration by publication** through TBBs and inheritance
- **Configuration based on user, group, or publication** through authorization

Gotchas include script that modifies the RTF, making sure extensions work in XPM, and an event system approach might need "find and update" or synchronization features.

Comment: hi alvin, i'm not sure i can even understand this - perhaps could you elaborate on this: "Flipping the requirement by restricting script by default. Only certain groups can add script in RTF (or maybe just in "code" components)." - how is that implementable ootb without extension ??

Comment: Using the same embedded schema everywhere with an XSLT filter that prevents script gives you a "default setup" that prevents script in RTF. Then you need to give only certain groups the ability to put in code--think "[content injection](http://www.tridionworld.com/articles/understanding_content_injection.aspx)" with a component link. Then "inject" the actual code during publish. I'll update the answer.